# Is there Firefox addon to identify performance problems in web applications?

Tags: firefox, performance, browser-addons, website, web-development

I want a Firefox add-on to know where time is being spent in my Web Application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Yahoo's YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), it works in combination with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Firefox addon.

> YSlow analyzes web pages and suggests
>   ways to improve their performance
>   based on a set of rules for high
>   performance web pages. YSlow is a
>   Firefox add-on integrated with the
>   Firebug web development tool. YSlow
>   grades web page based on one of three
>   predefined ruleset or a user-defined
>   ruleset. It offers suggestions for
>   improving the page's performance,
>   summarizes the page's components,
>   displays statistics about the page,
>   and provides tools for performance
>   analysis, including Smush.it™ and
>   JSLint.

Another option is the [Charles web debugging proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It's a very useful tool for web application development in general (both javascript and flash), and one of the features is a chart showing all the objects/requests loaded, and the time they take.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) (again with Firebug) would be another option.

Answer (score 1):

There is the new [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/) by Google.

Comment: It needs Google chrome and not work with Firefox. isn't ?

Comment: Yes. It's a Chrome/Chromium extension. I'm sorry it's not exactly an answer.